# How to print values in an Interative Fashion?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

Below contents are stored in an file.
& i wish to use AWK for the desired output... (or a sample shell script).

Original Content.

```
 A 193
 A  27
 B  82
 B 496
 C 117
 D 251
 D   3
 E  26
 E 151.... and so on.
```

I need the above contents to be Numbered in an Interative Fashion w.r.t to its Individual Instance.

i.e. output should be

```
 A_1=27
 A_2=193
 B_1=82
 B_2=496
 C_1=117
 D_1=251
 D_2=3
 E_1=26
 E_2=151.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ cat test.txt
A 193
A  27
B  82
B 496
C 117
D 251
D   3
E  26
E 151
$ awk '{printf("%s_%d=%s\n", $1, ++num[$1], $2)}' test.txt
A_1=193
A_2=27
B_1=82
B_2=496
C_1=117
D_1=251
D_2=3
E_1=26
E_2=151
```

Comment: @Venkatesh, Any reason for unaccept? If this does not work, please let me know.